# WebOS. Autorun application, after reboot system

Tags: javascript, webos

When I turn off the TV on my application, when I turn it on it does not open. How can I fix this?
WebOS version is 4.9.0
For example, the Netflix application, I do this on my TV

After experimenting a bit, I found a way. I added `"supportGIP": true` to `appinfo.json`. And then in the application `webOS.service.request("luna://com.webos.service.eim")` with method parameters: `"addDevice"` and others. At first I thought it worked. But then I switched to another application, YouTube, and turned off the TV again, and when I turned it on, my application opened again